# awk: Use gensub to substitute multiple lines from a paragraph record

Tags: regex, awk, substitution

I have an input file with multiple paragraphs separated by at least two newlines (`\n\n`), and I'm wanting to extract fields from lines within certain paragraphs.  I think the processing will be simplest if I can get `gensub` to work as I'm hoping.  Considering the following input file:

```
[Record R1]
    Var1=0
    Var2=20
    Var3=5

[Record R2]
    Var1=10
    Var3=9
    Var4=/var/tmp/
    Var2=12

[Record R3]
    Var1=2
    Var3=5
    Var5=19
```

I want to print only the value of `Var2` from records `R1` and `R3` (where `Var2` doesn't actually exist).  I can easily group all of the variables into their corresponding record by setting `RS="\n\n"`, then they are all contained within `$0`.  But since I don't know where it will appear it the list ahead of time, I want to use something like gensub to extract it.  This is what I have going:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        RS="\n\n"
    }
    /Record R1/ || /Record R3/ {
        print gensub(/[\n.]*Var2=(.*)[\n.]*/, "\\1", "g", $0)
    }
' /tmp/input.txt
```

But instead of only printing `20` (the value of Var2 from R1), it prints the following:

```
[Record R1]
    Var1=0
    20
    Var3=5
[Record R3]
    Var1=2
    Var3=5
    Var5=19
```

The intent is that the regex in the gensub command would capture all characters (newlines: `\n`; and non-newlines: `.`) before and after `Var2=XX` and replace everything with `XX`.  But instead, it's only capturing the characters on the same line as `Var2=XX`.  Can `awk`'s `gensub` do this kind of multi-line substitution?

I know an alternative would be to loop over all the fields in the record, the split the field that matches `Var2=` on the `=` sign, but that feels less efficient as I scale this out to multiple variables.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what it is you're trying to do with gensub() but to do what you seem to be trying to do in any awk is:

```
awk -F'[][[:space:]=]+' '{f[$2]=$3} !NF{if (f["Record"]~/^R[12]$/) print f["Var2"]; delete f}' file
20
12

awk -F'[][[:space:]=]+' '{f[$2]=$3} !NF{if (f["Record"]~/^R[13]$/) print f["Var2"]; delete f}' file
20
```

gensub() doesn't care if the string it's operating on is one line or many lines btw - `\n` is just one more character, no different from any other character.

Oh, hang on, now I see what you're thinking with that gensub() - your problems are:

1. `[\n.]*` means `zero or more newlines or periods` but you don't have
   any periods in your input so it's the same as `\n*` but you don't have any newlines immediately before a `Var2`
2. `Var2` doesn't exist in your 2nd records so the regexp can't match it.
3. The `(.*)` will match everything to the end of the record (leftmost longest matches).
4. The `"g"` is misleading since you only expect 1 match.

So using gensub() on multi-line text isn't an issue, your regexps just wrong.

Comment: Thanks Ed.  I like this approach of building up an array.  I think it will be less expensive than gensub in the long run.  This also led me to the answer I was looking for with gensub: `gensub(/.*Var2=([^\n]*).*/, "\\1", "g", $0)`.  It would have to be updated to account for when `Var2` doesn't exist in the record, but it's the main part I was looking for.

Comment: The performance doesn't really matter in this case, the important thing with my approach is that you end up with an associative array of names to values so it's trivial to test/print whatever values you want just by their name. wrt your comment abut using gensub() that `It would have to be updated to account for when Var2 doesn't exist` - not exactly, it'd require completely different code to handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -v RS= '/\[Record R[13]\]/{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
                                   {v=sub(/ *Var2=/,"",$i);
                                    if(v) print $i}}' file

20
```